# Using Ajax.BeginForm in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have something like

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Next", "Controll", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "updateRegion", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }))
{
 <div id="updateRegion">
 @Html.Partial("_callingFromPartial", Model.List[0])
</div>
}


       @Html.RadioButtonFor(item => Model.OptionSelected, Model.IdOption, new { id = "select" + Model.IdOption })
       <label>@Model.OptionText</label>
       <input type="submit" value="Next"/>


[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Next(Bu.Models.ChoiceQuestion itemReturn)
    {
        CurrentItem = Itens[refe+1];
        return PartialView("_callingFromPartial", CurrentItem);
    }
```

But it's not working like I want, I'm trying to load the next content in #updateRegion, but it's showing "The resource cannot be found." , is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: The problem was the "method='post'" default in the form, now I change this with 
'Ajax.BeginForm("Next", "Controll", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "updateRegion", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET", **new {method = "get"}** }'
and it's working, however, it's still showing the result in a clean document page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
First of all you are in div that needs to be replaces
i.e. updateRegion
According to your code it will replace everything

```
new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "updateRegion", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
```

You will need to declare div within for and around elements which needs to be replaced.

Partial views are suggested in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try  placing div "updateRegion" inside the form tag. 
Like :-

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Next", "Controll", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "updateRegion", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }))
{ 
  <div id="updateRegion">
  </div>
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(item => Model.OptionSelected, Model.IdOption, new { id = "select" + Model.IdOption })
  <label>@Model.OptionText</label>
  <input type="submit" value="Next" />
}
```