# How do I instantly get updated value of dropdown box selected item in C# MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, scaffolding

I have a list of "practices" that I need to filter on based on user selection. My view has a dropdown that looks like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("practice", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PracticeList)
```

It allows the user to select one of 6 or so practices to filter another list on. I need to retrieve the value and have the page updated. I have the page filling with the valued by default without mind to the practice filter, I just can't update it because I can't seem to retrieve the value. I just need to get this value so I can incorporate it into my loop to rebuild the list.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{      
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Email)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBox("Hours")
    </td>        
</tr>
}
```

Comment: You could do it using jQuery, Knockout too.

Comment: There's no need to convolute the code, it's a .cshtml file (as is the rest of the project), adding JS into the mix seems unnecessary.

Comment: If you don't want to use any jQuery, then you can do it by posting to the action, and then proceeding to step 2 where you have the second drop down filled with desired options based on selected value on the first drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Start by using jquery to capture a change in the select:

```
$('#selectList').on('change', function() {

})
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csLAk/)

then, ajax to a controller that will return your other items:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")',
    data: { 'selection' : $(this).val() },
    type: "post",
    cache: false,
    success: function (items) {
        //update the other select
    };
});
```

Using Razor:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "DivToUpdate"}))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("practice", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PracticeList, new { onchange="this.form.submit()"})
}
```

you could then return the dropdownlist from your controller, or however you want to handle that.

**EDIT**

Actually, I don't think you'll be able to use the Ajax.BeginForm approach as you would have nested forms.  You may be stuck with jQuery

Comment: Not anti JS at all actually. It's just this is a C#/ASP.NET project and I'm going for code cohesion. My javascript is good, but I'm learning MVC and ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

You can also use @Ajax.BeginForm and in the action of the controller return partial view and render it on the client side in the success handler of the ajax form.

Here a post on @Ajax.BeginForm

[Using Ajax.BeginForm in MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849333/using-ajax-beginform-in-mvc4)

But you will have to have a jquery script that submits the form on your select change event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AjaxBeginFormfor like this:

```
@model YourModel
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", null,
                            new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST",
                                OnSuccess = "functionIfYouWant(data)",
                                 UpdateTargetId = "divid",
                                 InsertionMode=InsertionMode.InsertAfter},
                                new { id = "formId" }))
     {
       @Html.DropDownListFor(c=>c.SelectedVal, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PracticeList)
    <div id="divId">

    </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
//or add @Html.DropDownListFor(c=>c.SelectedVal, //  List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.PracticeList,new {onChange="jQuery("#formId").submit()"})
        }
```

Now you can post model to controller and the returned content will be appended to content of div that have id="divId"
Hope you understand what I was trying to explain .
Also try to avoid ViewBag in your aplciation is not good practice.Try to use SelectlistItem in your model to populate dropdown.
so suppose you have your model:

```
public class Model
{
public int SelectedItem{get;set;}
public IList<DropDownObj> ListObj{get;set;
public IList<SelectListItem> SelectListItemListObj{get;set;}
        {
            get
            {
                   var list = (from item in ListObj
                            select new SelectListItem()
                            {
                                Text = item.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                Value item.Name
                            }).ToList();
                return list;
            }
            set{}
        } 
} 

public class DropDownObj
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;
}
```

In controller you will need to set(populate from db or from somewhere ) your list of DropDownObj.
and in view you will be able to do something like this :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(c=>c.SelectedItem,Model.SelectListItemListObj)
```

This is how mvc dropdownlsit should look in mvc.